# Org Mode group tags not working (org-tags-expand: Wrong type argument)

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I keep getting the following error when I go into agenda view and try to filter by tag (`C-c a t / TAB` PC `RET`):

```
org-tags-expand: Wrong type argument: listp, #("{\\<\\(?:pc\\(?:desktop\\|mobile\\)?\\)\\>}" 0  36 (grouptag t))
```

This is how the tags are defined in the same file:

```
#+TAGS: { PC : PCDesktop PCMobile }
```

I am using Emacs Version 24.4 (9.0) on OS X Yosemite. The org-mode version is

```
Org-mode version 8.3beta (release_8.3beta-669-g077a24 @ /Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/Resources/lisp/org/)
```

I have tried using a stable release and then updated to the beta and I'm still having the same problem. I'm having this problem with any group tag I set. It also happens when I create a custom agenda command.

The following is my .emacs file:

```
;;   -*- mode: lisp  -*-
;; Disable the splash screen (to enable it agin, replace the t with 0)
(setq inhibit-splash-screen t)
(set-face-attribute 'default nil :height 120)

;; Enable transient mark mode
(transient-mark-mode 1)

;;;;org-mode configuration
;; Enable org-mode
(require 'org)
;;(setq org-todo-keywords
;;  '((sequence "TODO" "IN-PROGRESS" "WAITING" "DONE")))
;; The following lines are always needed.  Choose your own keys.
;;      (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.org\\'" . org-mode)) ; not needed since Emacs 22.2
;;      (add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'turn-on-font-lock) ; not needed when global-font-lock-mode is on
  (global-set-key "\C-cl" 'org-store-link)
  (global-set-key "\C-ca" 'org-agenda)
  (global-set-key "\C-cb" 'org-iswitchb)
;; Make org-mode work with files ending in .org
;; (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.org$" . org-mode))
;; The above is the default in recent emacsen
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(org-agenda-custom-commands
   (quote
    (("cs" "Available SCHOOL"
      ((tags-todo "SCHOOL-TODO=\"WAITING\"-Container-SCHEDULED>\"<now>\"-Someday"
          ((org-agenda-overriding-header "Available SCHOOL")))
       (agenda ""
           ((org-agenda-overriding-header "Available SCHOOL")
        (org-agenda-tag-filter-preset
         (quote
          ("+SCHOOL")))
        (org-agenda-entry-types
         (quote
          (:deadline :timestamp))))))
      nil nil)
     ("ch" "Available HOME"
      ((tags-todo "HOME-TODO=\"WAITING\"-Container-SCHEDULED>\"<now>\"-Someday"
          ((org-agenda-overriding-header "Available HOME")))
       (agenda ""
       ((org-agenda-overriding-header "Deadlines HOME")
    (org-agenda-tag-filter-preset
     (quote
      ("+HOME")))
    (org-agenda-entry-types
     (quote
      (:deadline :timestamp))))))
  nil nil)
 ("ca" "Available ANYTIME"
  ((tags-todo "ANYTIME-TODO=\"WAITING\"-Container-SCHEDULED>\"<now>\"-Someday"
      ((org-agenda-overriding-header "Available ANYTIME")))
   (agenda ""
       ((org-agenda-overriding-header "Deadlines ANYTIME")
    (org-agenda-tag-filter-preset
     (quote
      ("+ANYTIME")))
    (org-agenda-entry-types
     (quote
      (:deadline :timestamp))))))
  nil nil)
 ("ce" "Available ERRANDS"
  ((tags-todo "ERRANDS-TODO=\"WAITING\"-Container-SCHEDULED>\"<now>\"-Someday"
      ((org-agenda-overriding-header "Available ERRANDS")))
   (agenda ""
       ((org-agenda-overriding-header "Deadlines ERRANDS")
    (org-agenda-tag-filter-preset
     (quote
      ("+ERRANDS")))
    (org-agenda-entry-types
     (quote
      (:deadline :timestamp))))))
  nil nil)
 ("cq" "Available PARENTS"
  ((tags-todo "PARENTS-TODO=\"WAITING\"-Container-SCHEDULED>\"<now>\"-Someday"
      ((org-agenda-overriding-header "Available PARENTS")))
   (agenda ""
       ((org-agenda-overriding-header "Deadlines PARENTS")
    (org-agenda-tag-filter-preset
     (quote
      ("+PARENTS")))
    (org-agenda-entry-types
     (quote
      (:deadline :timestamp))))))
  nil nil)
 ("ck" "Available KOBO"
  ((tags-todo "KOBO-TODO=\"WAITING\"-Container-SCHEDULED>\"<now>\"-Someday"
      ((org-agenda-overriding-header "Available KOBO")))
   (agenda ""
       ((org-agenda-overriding-header "Deadlines KOBO")
    (org-agenda-tag-filter-preset
     (quote
      ("+KOBO")))
    (org-agenda-entry-types
     (quote
      (:deadline :timestamp))))))
  nil nil)
 ("cn" "Available PHONE"
  ((tags-todo "PHONE-TODO=\"WAITING\"-Container-SCHEDULED>\"<now>\"-Someday"
      ((org-agenda-overriding-header "Available PHONE")))
   (agenda ""
       ((org-agenda-overriding-header "Deadlines PHONE")
    (org-agenda-tag-filter-preset
     (quote
      ("+PHONE")))
    (org-agenda-entry-types
     (quote
      (:deadline :timestamp))))))
  nil nil)
 ("cp" "Available PC"
  ((tags-todo "PC-TODO=\"WAITING\"-Container-SCHEDULED>\"<now>\"-Someday"
      ((org-agenda-overriding-header "Available PC")))
   (agenda ""
       ((org-agenda-overriding-header "Deadlines PC")
    (org-agenda-tag-filter-preset
     (quote
      ("+PC")))
    (org-agenda-entry-types
     (quote
      (:deadline :timestamp))))))
  nil nil)
 ("cx" "Available PCDesktop"
  ((tags-todo "PCDesktop-TODO=\"WAITING\"-Container-SCHEDULED>\"<now>\"-Someday"
      ((org-agenda-overriding-header "Available PCDesktop")))
   (agenda ""
       ((org-agenda-overriding-header "Deadlines PCDesktop")
    (org-agenda-tag-filter-preset
     (quote
      ("+PCDesktop")))
    (org-agenda-entry-types
     (quote
      (:deadline :timestamp))))))
  nil nil)
 ("cy" "Available PCMobile"
  ((tags-todo "PCMobile-TODO=\"WAITING\"-Container-SCHEDULED>\"<now>\"-Someday"
      ((org-agenda-overriding-header "Available PCMobile")))
   (agenda ""
       ((org-agenda-overriding-header "Deadlines PCMobile")
    (org-agenda-tag-filter-preset
     (quote
      ("+PCMobile")))
    (org-agenda-entry-types
     (quote
      (:deadline :timestamp))))))
  nil nil)
 ("cw" "Available WORK"
  ((tags-todo "WORK-TODO=\"WAITING\"-Container-SCHEDULED>\"<now>\"-Someday"
      ((org-agenda-overriding-header "Available WORK")))
   (agenda ""
       ((org-agenda-overriding-header "Deadlines WORK")
    (org-agenda-tag-filter-preset
     (quote
      ("+WORK")))
    (org-agenda-entry-types
     (quote
      (:deadline :timestamp))))))
  nil nil))))
 '(org-agenda-dim-blocked-tasks (quote invisible))
 '(org-agenda-files (quote ("~/GTD.org")))
 '(org-enforce-todo-dependencies t)
 '(org-tags-exclude-from-inheritance
   (quote
    ("Project" "Folder" "Taskgroup" "Single_Action_List"))))
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 )
```

I have made sure `org-group-tags` is set to not nil. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The format you are using for tags appears to be different than the manual:  http://orgmode.org/manual/Setting-tags.html#Setting-tags  Perhaps that is the problem?  The closest example to what you are using is this:  `#+TAGS: { @work(w)  @home(h)  @tennisclub(t) }  laptop(l)  pc(p)`  There is something inside the braces [*without* using colons], **and** there is something to the right of the braces.

Comment: Thanks for your input @lawlist. The format I'm using is the "Tag group" format.
In `{ PC : PCDesktop PCMobile }` `PC` should represent both `PCDesktop` and `PCMobile`. So a search for `PC` should be expanded to include both. My hunch is that the expansion is where the problem is occurring.

Comment: Does the error go away if you eliminate `PC :` ?  The manual describes methods for conducting an advanced search containing multiple tags:  http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/advanced-searching.html

Comment: The error does go away if I don't use Tag groups. I understand I an find alternatives to using tag groups, Im just at a loss for why a documented feature does not work as expected.